# Looking to Scrape Data from Interactive Graph From Voting Website

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, graph, interactive

I am looking to pull data points from the *Voter Precinct Transmission by Region* graph from this [website](https://www.rappler.com/nation/elections/forty-seven-percent-ratio-law-large-numbers-polls/).

[Photo of Desired Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s1lI.png)

My method to collect the data was to go through the Inspect -> Network tab feature to locate the json or js file type, download it, and convert into tabulated data. This was my approach from other polling sites for time series for each specific candidate and even final count per province, but I cannot seem to find time series data for each respective province except for this graph.

I am not overly familiar with Python webscraping packages such as Beautiful Soup or Selenium but willing to learn if need be.

Solutions much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Use network tab. You are looking for several XHRs similar to `https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/9898342/embed`

Comment: @QHarr Thank you! I was looking through the network tab and never knew it could be under embedded. Do you know an approach to scrape the data points on the graph to a table by any chance?